# Interpolation The coordinates do not lie on a structured tensor product grid

Tags: interpolation

I have a big array of multidimentional data 50 Mb, 500 000 elements. and I want to interpolate it and make a normal function.

Please do not mark this question as a duplicate straightaway, because I read many answers and they actually do not answer my question, they are a little bit different. I do not ask how to fix this problem, but more about definition and a way to find where my data is wrong.

Data example is this:

```
{
  {{-0.5, -0.4898989898989899, 1., 0., 0.1}, 0.10120921662021362},
  {{-0.5, -0.4898989898989899, 1., 0.12566370614359174, 0.1}, 0.1012092163684851},
  {{-0.5, -0.4898989898989899, 1., 0.25132741228718347, 0.1}, 0.10120921611675658},
  {{-0.5, -0.4898989898989899, 1., 0.37699111843077515, 0.1}, 0.10120921586502805},
  {{-0.5, -0.4898989898989899, 1., 0.5026548245743669, 0.1}, 0.10120921561329953},
  {{-0.5, -0.4898989898989899, 1., 0.6283185307179586, 0.1}, 0.101209215361571}
}
```

This small example works fine, but when I try to interpolate all my data, I get this error

Interpolation::indim: The coordinates do not lie on a structured tensor product grid.

My questions are:

1. What is "structured tensor product grid"? Can someone give me example of "structured tensor product grid" and "NOT structured tensor product grid"? Might be I will be able to change my data accordingly, but I could not find definition of this term anywhere.
2. Is there any way to find in my big data list (50 Mb) this place, where deviation (something wrong) happens? In other words how to find where my data is wrong?

Comment: What version of *Mathematica* are you using?  Are you reasonably certain your data does fall on a regular grid?  Do you still get an error if you use `Interpolation[ <your_data>, InterpolationOrder -> 1]`?

Comment: As JasonB states, your data must be laid out in a multi-dimensional rectangular array.  Change `1.` to `1.0000000001` for any one of your data points in the example in your question, and you will see that `Interpolation` no longer works.

Answer (score 4):

`Interpolation` requires that the data be laid out on a multidimensional (in this case, 4D) grid that is the product of 1D grids.  A quick check is provided by comparing the number of data points, here,

```
Length[data[[All, 1]]]
(* 6 *)
```

with the size of the product of the four 1D grids, here

```
Times @@ (Length@Union[data[[All, 1, #]]] & /@ Range[4])
(* 6 *)
```

As observed in the question, `Interpolation` returns an `InterpolatonFunction` for `data`.

Suppose, however, that one instance of `1.` is replaced by `1.0000000001`; call this new array `data1`.  Then,

```
Times @@ (Length@Union[data1[[All, 1, #]]] & /@ Range[4])
(* 12 *)
```

which is greater than the number of data points.  Thus, the grid in this case is incomplete, and `Interpolation` fails.  Finding the offending data points can be tedious for large arrays.  Here are the 1D grids for `data1`.

```
Gather[data1[[All, 1, #]]] & /@ Range[4]
(* {{{-0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5}}, 
    {{-0.489899, -0.489899, -0.489899, -0.489899, -0.489899, -0.489899}}, 
    {{1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}, {1.}}, 
    {{0.}, {0.125664}, {0.251327}, {0.376991}, {0.502655}, {0.628319}}} *)
```

The final `{1.}` really is ``1.0000000001`, but not all the digits are shown in the notebook output.  Looking for things like this can help to identify the offending grid points.